# Rename an app folder in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, directory, rename

I've been trying to find how I can rename an app folder in Symfony 2, but I couldn't find anything. I think it's feasible but I don't know how to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I've renamed all 'app' to 'kernel' in app.php and app_dev.php. When I start server I get "The file "D:/wolendev/app/config/config_dev.yml".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your `composer.json` file. Specifically:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

Change `symfony-app-dir` to the value that you want. You will also have to change the path to `incenteev-parameters.file` and any other paths that might explicitly target the `app` dir.

Then... you will need to change some paths in your `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` files accordingly. For example:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../apps/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
// in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
// also using APC.
/*
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../apps/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../apps/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The `$loader` and `require_once` paths will have to change. I assume a cache clear and composer update might be required too.

It should work fine then. The documentation discusses [overriding the default file structure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html) but it doesn't say anything about the `app` dir. However, I did a quick test here and it seems to work fine here. YMMV!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Wolen no problem! I updated the answer there, so there might be some more detail in there that might help.